# Html 5 Grid Drawing Problem

Tags: javascript, html, memory-leaks, setinterval, html5-canvas

```
    //Set the number of rows and columns for the board
var rows = 10;
var columns = 10;
var offset= 0.5;

//Create the board, setting random squares to be obstacles
        var board = [];

for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            board[x] = [];

            for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                    board[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }

function draw_grid(size, amount, ctx){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFF";
    for (var i=0.5; i<size*amount+1; i+=size){
        ctx.moveTo(0,i);
        ctx.lineTo(size*amount, i);
        ctx.moveTo(i,0);
        ctx.lineTo(i, size*amount);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function update_grid(grid, ctx){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    for (var i=0; i<grid.length; i+=1){
        for (var a=0; a<grid[i].length; a+=1){
            if (grid[i][a]==1){
                ctx.fillRect((i*32)+offset, (a*32)+offset, 32, 32);
            }
        }
    }
}

game_area = document.getElementById("a");
context = game_area.getContext('2d');
board[0][3] = 1;

function on_enter_frame(){

    context.clearRect(0,0, game_area.width, game_area.height);
    context.fillStyle = "#28F";
    context.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
    draw_grid(32, 10, context);
    update_grid(board, context);

}

setInterval(on_enter_frame,30);
```

This code seems to be eating up a lot of memory, does anyone have any idea of why? Just started programming in html5... I believe that it has something to do with the for loops in the update_grid function, help apreciated

Comment: Since you tagged this as `lag`, do you mean it's slow or does it really take up a bunch of memory?

Comment: "programming in html5" You're programming in [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), HTML5 is the specifiaction for the DOM, which is manipulated…

Comment: lag in the sense that this is eating up too much memory and eventually firefox crashes...

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you're doing a lot of calculations in your loops and your setInterval period is very short - do you need to update your grid so frequently?

In your draw_grid() function you're calculating size*amount 3 times, why not do it once at the outside the loop as a local variable and reuse that variable where you need it?

An alternative way of doing your painting may be to use [mozRequestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame), it may be more efficient if you need to do your painting so frequently.

Comment: thanks, solved by lowering fps and creating a background canvas

Answer (score 0):

```
game_area = document.getElementById("a");
context = game_area.getContext('2d');
```

Both those variables are declared without using the var keyword... dangerous to do that and can cause memory leaks depending upon how you're using them.

This is the way forward:

```
var game_area = document.getElementById("a");
var context = game_area.getContext('2d');
```

Also it is good practise not to access global variables because the JavaScript VM has to do a lookup that is quite costly. A better way would be to do this:

```
function on_enter_frame(pContext, pGame_area, pBoard){

    pContext.clearRect(0,0, pGame_area.width, pGame_area.height);
    pContext.fillStyle = "#28F";
    pContext.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
    draw_grid(32, 10, pContext);
    update_grid(pBoard, pContext);

}
```

Then call that method with the required parameters that exist in the current scope already:

```
on_enter_frame(context, game_area, board);
```

Comment: for some reason, this format: setInterval(on_enter_frame(context, game_area, board),30) is not working. Would you happen to enlighten me as to why this is happening?

Comment: setInterval(on_enter_frame(context, game_area, board),30) will not work because rather than asking setInterval to call that method with those arguments every 30 milliseconds, you are effectively asking it to:

1: call on_enter_frame(context, game_area, board)
2: setInterval to call the result of on_enter_frame(context, game_area, board) - which is not a function

The correct setInterval usage is to pass a function rather than the result of a function call.